# 504 ошибка в wget

Tags: linux, crontab, wget

Ставлю задание в планировщик на хостинге:

```
wget http://example.ru/myscript
```

Скрипт должен выполняться в начале каждого часа. Выполняется он довольно долго, может до часа доходить. Крон выполняет задание, почему-то получает 504 ошибку (хотя скрипт продолжает работать) и пытается еще раз запустить задачу. В итоге он запускает несколько экземпляров скрипта, что приводит к дублированию записей в базу данных. Можно ли как-то настроить команду wget, чтобы  она не учитывала ответ сервера и не пыталась перезапустить задание, получая 504 ошибку?

Сам скрипт работает корректно.

Comment: Попробуйте флаг --content-on-error

Comment: А что делает этот флаг? Что-то не могу инфу о нем найти

Comment: Если этот флаг установлен, то wget не будет пропускать контент, когда сервер отвечает кодом ошибки http (т.е. должен игнорировать возвращаемый код ошибки)

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Затещу.

Comment: запуск скрипта без участия http-сервера выглядит более разумным решением.

Comment: Все работает через роутер сайта, поэтому проще так

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, заменив wget на curl:

```
curl -s http://example.ru/myscript > /dev/null
```